# jQuery Validation attaches only to the first form

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, select

I have issue validating if user submits default select options
Here is a sample form :

```
    <form action="/shopping-cart" method="post" class="eshop addtocart"   id="eshopprod7751562209795">
    <fieldset>
    <span class="eshop eselect"><label for="exopt1001562209795">Choose Size and Type…  </label><br>
    <select class="cartselectclass" id="exopt1001562209795" name="optset[0][id]"><option value="" selected="selected">Choose Option...</option>
    <option value="129">8" x 10" – Print + $9.95</option>
    <option value="130">11" x 14" – Print + $19.95</option>
    <option value="131">16" x 20" – Canvas + $299.00</option>
    </select>
   </span>
  <label for="qty7751562209795" class="qty"><abbr title="Quantity">Qty</abbr>:</label>
  <input type="text" value="1" id="qty7751562209795" maxlength="3" size="3" name="qty"   class="iqty">
   <input class="button mybutton" value="Add to Cart" title="Add selected item to your shopping basket" type="submit">
   </fieldset>
   </form>
```

and here is the jquery for validating the select option:
What I am trying is if user accidently clicks on add to cart, they will get alert if they have not choosen any options by default "Choose Options" is selected.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('select.cartselectclass option:first-child').remove();

    $('.cartselectclass').prepend('<option value="" selected="selected">Choose Option...</option>').val('');
    $('.mybutton').click(function(){

        if ($('.cartselectclass').val()=='')
        {           
                        alert('Please choose at least one option.');
            return false;
        }

    })

    $('.addtocart').submit(function(){

        var Id =$(this).attr("id");
        var data = {action: 'eshop_special_action',post:$('#'+Id).serialize() };
        $.post(""+eshopCartParams.adminajax, data,
            function(response){

            $('#'+Id +" .eshopajax").insertAfter(this).fadeIn(100).html(response).fadeOut(3000);
            setTimeout (cleareshopCart,1000);
            setTimeout (doeshopRequest,750);
            setTimeout (cleareshopRequest,3000);
        });

        function doeshopRequest(){
            var tdata = {action: 'eshop_cart'};
            $.post(""+eshopCartParams.adminajax, tdata,
            function(response){
                $(".ajaxcart").insertAfter(this).fadeOut(50).html(response).fadeIn(700);
            });
        }
        function cleareshopRequest(){
            $(".eshopajax").empty();
        }
        function cleareshopCart(){
            $(".ajaxcart").insertAfter();
        }
        return false;


    });

});
```

Comment: I don't understand how this question has anything to do with jquery validation

Comment: `$('.cartselectclass').val()` returns the value of the first element with class `cartselectclass`. You need to modify your selector to grab the correct element. Also, I think linking to a question about the jQuery Validation plugin, which you appear to not be using, could just cause additional confusion.

Comment: Sorry, for putting the link of jquery validation plugin.
the above codes works for the first form but I have multiple forms on the same page, it doesnot work with the other forms, when I select other options in the next forms it only gives alert donot allow me to add to cart.

Comment: Hi, I have fixed the issue myself, it was selector :
 var Id =$(this).attr("id");
   var formId = $('#'+Id).closest('form').attr("id");

   
   var selval = $('#'+formId).find('.cartselectclass').attr("id");
   
   
   if ($('#'+selval).val()=='')
   {   
       alert('Please choose at least one option.');
    return false;
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the selector to grab correct element.

```
var Id =$(this).attr("id"); var formId = $('#'+Id).closest('form').attr("id"); 
var selval = $('#'+formId).find('.cartselectclass').attr("id"); if ($('#'+selval).val()=='') {     
alert('Please choose at least one option.'); return false; }
```